# volume slider has no effect

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer, avplayer, mpvolumeview

I am creating a radio streaming app with play, pause and volume slider.

I have implemented volume slider using `MPVolumeView` but unfortunately it is not working.

Can any one please let me know the correct code so that the volume slider will work in my app. I have used `MPMoviePlayerController`, `AVPlayer`, `AVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: By "not working" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Hi,Not working in the sense volume is not adjusting. I am unable to control the volume defined in the app.please help me..

Comment: You have to implemented MPVolumeView, so you are doing a good direction. Paste your code out, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you missed an important part of Apple's documentation; 
[Working with Movies and iPod Music](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies.html)

I am suspecting that you are using both, `AVAudioPlayer` and `MPMoviePlayerController` together and that you have setup some audio session attributes to get that working properly. Now when doing so, you may want to tell `MPMoviePlayerController` to use that session / or not.

> Using the Media Player Framework Exclusively
>
> If your application is using a movie player only, or a music player
>   only—and you are not playing your own sounds—then you should not
>   configure an audio session.
>
> If you are using a movie player exclusively, you must tell it to use
>   its own audio session, as follows:

```
myMoviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO
```

> If you are using a movie
>   player and a music player, then you probably want to configure how the
>   two interact; for this, you must configure an audio session, even
>   though you are not playing application audio per se. Use the guidance
>   in Table 6-1.

[image]